# Maps between two line bundles versus sections of their tensor product

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, vector-bundles

There is a point about maps betwen line bundles (continuous or smooth or holomorphic --- I don't think it matters for this question) that is glossed over in many texts.

A map from one line bundle $N_1$ to another $N_2$ over the same space $X$ is a map $h$ that makes a commutative triangle with the projections to $X$.

These maps form a vector space over the base field, and we will call this vector space $\mbox{Hom}_X(N_1,N_2)$.  Let's fix the base field to be $\mathbb C$ and take the fibres of the $N_i$ to be copies of $\mathbb C$, to make things concrete.

On the other hand, maps between $N_1$ and $N_2$ can also be thought of as (continuous, smooth, holomorphic) global sections of the line bundle $N_1^*\otimes N_2$, i.e. as elements of $H^0(X;\mathcal O(N_1^*\otimes N_2))$, where $\mathcal O$ denotes the sheaf of continuous or smooth or holomorpic sections, as appropriate.

**Question:**

Why is $\mbox{Hom}_X(N_1,N_2)=H^0(X;\mathcal O(N_1^*\otimes N_2))$, at least as sets?  (Once set-theoretic equivalence is established, the vector space isomorphism should come for free.)

The reason why these two view points on line bundle maps are equivalent is not explained in any of the standard texts that I use.

I understand the correspondence at the level of a single fibre, i.e. the linear algebra of why maps from one copy of $\mathbb C$ into another copy are given by $\mathbb C^*\otimes\mathbb C$.  But thinking at the level of open sets or globally, a bundle map from the first view point is a map between the total spaces of $N_1$ and $N_2$ that commutes with projections to $X$.  From the second point of view, it is a map from the space $X$ into the total space of $N_1^*\otimes N_2$ that commutes with a projection to $X$.  **How can I reconcile these?**

(As part of the question, I'm also not sure how the projection of $N_1^*\otimes N_2$ to $X$ is determined by the data of $N_1$ and $N_2$.  I understand how the *transition functions* of the tensor product relate to those of $N_1$ and $N_2$ --- I'm not asking about that. How is the *projection map* for the tensor product is obtained?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint.** Think first about the case where X is a point, where this reduces to linear algebra. The general case is exactly the same.

Comment: As for your parenthetical question as the end: you should certainly review the construction of the tensor product of bundles —indeed, it is rather surprising that you are even asking your main question if you are quite unsure about what the tensor product of bundles is!

Comment: Well, i did. *Exactly* the same thing happens over a point and over a general X. A map f of bundles $M\to N$is a choice, for each point x of X, of a linear map $f_x:M_x\to N_x$ over the corresponding fibers, which is, by linear algebra, the same thing as an element $t_x$ of $M_x^*\otimes N_x$, which is the fiber of the bundle $M^*\otimes N$ over x (essentially by definition) This defines a section t of the bundle $M^*\otimes N$.

Comment: That is what I suggested you to think about in the case of a point—notice that the assignment from f to t does not depend at all on whether X is a point or not, and that was my point. Of course, for this to work one has to prove that the section is smooth if f is a smooth bundle map and that one does obtain a bijection in this way, and so on. To do that, you will need to review the construction of the tensor product, as among other things you will need to know its projection map is.

Comment: Thanks, I sincerely appreciate the extra detail.  I understand what you are saying, but perhaps it is just my question that is unclear.  Using your notation, how does the fact that $\pi\circ t=\mbox{id}$, where $\pi$ is the projection of the tensor product onto $X$, translate into $f$ making a commutative triangle with the individual projections of the two line bundles?  This is really the only thing that is bothering me, and which I can't seem to coax out with diagrams.

Comment: I started with f, which is a bundle map. This is what allowed me to consider the restriction f_x, which determines an element t_x in the fiber of the tensor product over x. That is the reason why t is a section. The questIon in your comment is backwards, as I started with f and constructed t.

Comment: I'd rarher not. I am a firm believer thar understanding is a process, and often comments capture that process much better than an answer which appears ex nihilo.

Comment: By the way, in your question you wrote that you understood what happens over a fiber, but what little you wrote about it made is clear that you identified thw fibers with C. That never helps—in my second comment above I did not do that, for example. You should try to avoid it :-)

Comment: Mariano, if I can ask for just one more clarification: are morphisms between $M$ and $N$ in correspondence with sections of $M^*\otimes N$ or *global* sections of $M^*\otimes N$?  In other words, if $\{f_\alpha:U_\alpha\to\pi^{-1}(U_\alpha)\}$ is a set of functions specifying a section of the bundle $\pi:M^*\otimes N\to X$ (compatible with the transition functions), then do the $f_\alpha$'s need to agree on overlaps of the $U_\alpha$'s in order for $f$ to be a morphism from $M$ to $N$?

Comment: When you say «sections of $M^*\otimes N$», in opposition to «global sections», you mean sections over *what*? In any case, the $f_\alpha$ simply cannot agree on overlaps, as that does not make sense: their domains are different! The only possible condition of the $f_\alpha$ is that thet be compatible with transition functions.

Comment: Morphisms from $M$ to $N$ are in correspondence with sections of $M^*\otimes N$ over the whole space.

Comment: Global sections over $X$.  If agreeing on overlaps fundamentally does not make sense (i.e. $f_\alpha=f_\beta$ on $U_\alpha\cap U_\beta$), then how do you define $H^0(X;\mathcal O(M^*\otimes N))$?  It is the kernel of the boundary operator acting on $0$-cochains, and so it consists of sections in which  $f_\alpha=f_\beta$ on $U_\alpha\cap U_\beta$.  Yes or no?

Comment: Is $\mbox{Hom}(M,N)=H^0(X;\mathcal O(M^*\otimes N))$?  My question is about the "$H^0$".

Comment: Some books and papers *define* "global sections" to be the elements of $H^0$.  This is the convention I am following.

Comment: Dear MathsByTheSea, yes there is a canonical isomorphism  of complex vector spaces $Hom(M,N)=\Gamma(X,\mathcal O(M^*\otimes N)) $ valid for vector bundles $M, N$ of any rank. And, yes, the global secctions of any vector bundle $V$ are  indifferently denoted  $\Gamma(X,V)$ or $H^0(X,V)$.

Comment: Thanks, Georges.  What's confusing me is that $H^0(X;V):=\mbox{ker}(C^0(V)\stackrel{\delta}{\to}C^1(V))$, where $C^i(V)$ are $i$-cochains in sections of $V$ and $\delta$ is the boundary operator.  Hence, $H^0(X;M^*\otimes N)$ only contains maps $f$ from $M$ to $N$ whose local data $f_\alpha$ and $f_\beta$ agree on double overlaps $U_\alpha\cap U_\beta$.  But isn't this too strong a condition for what can be considered a bundle map?  For instance, when we define the Picard variety as $H^1(X;\mathcal O^*)$, this is literally the quotient of...

Comment: To define a section of any bundle, yes, the f_alpha must coincide on overlaps.

Comment: ...$\mbox{ker}(C^1(\mathcal O^*)\stackrel{\delta}{\to}C^2(\mathcal O^*))$ by $\mbox{im}(C^0(\mathcal O^*)\stackrel{\delta}{\to}C^1(\mathcal O^*))$.  In other words, the quotient of transition functions by automorphisms.  The automorphisms we are mod'ing out by (i.e. the $\mbox{im}(C^0\to C^1)$) don't seem to have to "agreeing" on overlap condition.

Comment: There **is** a difference between H^0 and H^1...

Comment: Mariano, I understand that.  Then can you explain why bundle maps from $M$ to itself are elements of $H^0(M^*\otimes M)=H^0(\mathcal O)=\mbox{ker}(C^0(\mathcal O)\stackrel{\delta}{\to}C^1(\mathcal O))$, but for the Picard group, we are mod'ing out by $\mbox{im}(C^0(\mathcal O^*)\stackrel{\delta}{\to}C^1(\mathcal O^*))$?

Comment: Because one is an H^O and the other an H^1.

Comment: Mariano, I'm certain that you are being very patient and that I might be trying that patience.   That being said: is a bundle automorphism a map from $M$ to itself that is invertible?  Assuming yes, then it should live in $H^0$, like the other bundle maps.  But when we are mod'ing out by automorphisms, we are mod'ing out not by things in $H^0$.  Or is the relationship between endomorphisms and automorphisms more like that between elements of a Lie algebra and a Lie group?

Comment: Of course, automorphisms of a bundle are endomorphisms which are invertible, as in pretty much every context. I honestly have no idea what your last comment is about. As automorphisms of what, exactly, are you viewing the elements of the Cartier group?

Comment: The cartier group can be described in many ways. One way is as the $H^O$ of the quotient $K^*/O^*$ of the sheaf of rational functions modulo the subsheaf of invertible regular functions. It can also be described as the $H^1$ of the sheaf $O^*$ of invertible regular functions. This is explained in most textbooks which deal both with Cartier divisors and cohomology; the very first result Google gives me is http://math.uchicago.edu/~cstaats/Charles_Staats_III/Notes_and_papers_files/CartierDivisors.pdf The two descriptions are useful.

Comment: You should really be asking what you are trying to ask in these comments in a separate question. My answer above answers your question on the top of this page. You seem to have unaccepted it out of what looks from my position like a tantrum —please do not reaccept it, but notice that this is not very usual behaviour in this site.

Comment: I un-accepted it not because of a "tantrum", but because I decided it was not complete enough for my liking.  I was going to mull it over a bit, before accepting again.  Also, I already did open a separate question, without your prompting.

Comment: Mariano, I'm sincerely pleased that you have entertained my questions, and appreciate your continued patience.  Please don't misinterpret my tone or intentions.  I simply want to learn, and I appreciate details.  Just like you believe that learning is a lengthy, careful process, I don't believe that the rating or acceptance of an answer is static.  You shouldn't take the un-acceptance personally.

Comment: If you believe that I am not appreciative enough of your answers or that I am too indecisive or prone to tantrum or whatever, then do us both a favour and simply ignore my questions. It does you no good to get worked up about my questions.  I'm being sincere.

Comment: Worked up? Heh. Oh well.

Comment: Well, you seem to have taken the un-acceptance personally, that's why I said "worked up".  I meant nothing personal by it, and I honestly didn't think it would even catch your attention, considering how busy you seem to be on this site.

Comment: Anyway, it seems like we both seem to misinterpret one another a lot, both our tone and our explanations to one another.  That's regrettable!  I'm happy to blame it on my hunger for small details combined with my mathematical immaturity (although Georges complimented me on my maturity on a different post!).  In the very short time I have been on this site, I have had very positive interactions with many folks.  I hope you and I can have more positive interactions in the future, maybe when I'm more up to speed on my geometry!! In the mean time, thanks as always for your assistance, Mariano. :-)

Comment: I have re-accepted the answer, and will work through everything we discussed in the comments (originally, I was going to wait until I finished doing that before re-accepting).  I now vow to save my prolific commenting abilities for other, perhaps more interesting posts!  ;-)